# finding a equation to fit a curve

Tags: linear-algebra, real-analysis, dynamic-programming

If I have a set of known values, i.e

```
   X        Y
0.81300, 4.9900
0.84500, 3.6900
0.86400, 3.0700
0.94000, 1.5000
0.94300, 1.4600
```

How would I make as accurate a curve as possible to fit all these points?

I have that the equation should be in the form of,

```
y=e^((x-c1)/c2)
```

or

```
x=c1+(c2 * ln(y))
```

So what I am really trying to do I suppose is find the constants C1 and C2.

So for the above C1 = 0.98291 and C2 = -0.10574.

The issue here is that I need to be able to compute C1 and C2 on the fly, in a program, where the X values of the above set can change, however The Y values will remain constant and be pre-determined.

It has been suggested I use Levenberg–Marquardt, and also that maybe I could do it with matrices and linear algebra. I however do not pretend to know where to start with Levenberg–Marquardt (how it works, what it does, or anything), and as for the Linear Algebra I am extremely rusty.

Anyone who could explain this for me and how I might compute it would have my gratitude and appreciation.

Also I should mention that the number of data point can be variable, but that shouldn't matter right? the More data sets the more accurate. (Unless I am wrong, boy I m out of my element.)

For matrices I was thinking about setting it up like this (again I do not know if I am doing this wrong)

```
        A         X         B
   | 1 ln(x1)|             |y1|
   | 1 ln(x2)|   |C1|   =  |y2|
   | 1 ln(x3)|   |C2|      |y3|
```

And then doing something like
X=(A(Transpose)A)^-1 * (A(Transpose)b)

Only I also don't know what exactly I am doing there

(Also I do not know if my tags are correct.)

Comment: Why not just do the same linear least squares fit at each time step, if your $Y$ values are fixed?

Comment: Also, Levenberg-Marquardt is a non-linear least squares algorithm, so I wouldn't use that if you don't need to.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $x=c_1+c_2 \ln{y}$?

Comment: yeah you are right it probably should be Levenberg–Marquardt, and the data is non linear, so for the highest accuracy we are trying to fit a curve, so non-linear is preferred. I do not know how to type matrices on this site or I would have shown what I was thinking there as well.

Comment: LM is a non-linear algorithm, but if you're data is logarithmic, as you've demonstrated, you can convert that to a linear problem. So you just solve the linear least squares problem after taking the log of the data, and then apply the exponential after the fact. There's no need to apply LM. It won't be more accurate. Unless of course, the data isn't exponential. But then you still need to find a function to fit to it anyhow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume that your data is of the form

$$x = c_1+c_2 \ln{y}$$

Then we may apply linear least-squares.  If we have $N$ measurements, then we have

$$\left ( \begin{array} \\x_1 \\x_2\\\cdots\\x_N\end{array} \right ) = \left ( \begin{array} \\1 & \ln{y_1} \\1 & \ln{y_2}\\\cdots\\1 & \ln{y_N}\end{array} \right ) \left ( \begin{array} \\c_1\\c_2\end{array}\right)$$

We may write in matrix form:

$$\mathbf{X} = \mathbf{A} \cdot \mathbf{C}$$

The least-squares formulation for $\mathbf{C}$ is as follows:

$$\mathbf{C}_{LS} = \left ( \mathbf{A}^T \mathbf{A}\right)^{-1} \mathbf{A}^T \mathbf{X}$$

You can work out the least-square coefficients explicitly:

$$c_1 = \frac{\sum_{n=1}^N x_n \sum_{k=1}^N \ln^2{y_k} - \sum_{n=1}^N x_n \ln{y_n} \sum_{k=1}^N \ln{y_k}}{\sum_{k=1}^N \ln^2{y_k}-\left ( \sum_{k=1}^N \ln{y_k}\right)^2} $$
$$c_2 = \frac{\sum_{n=1}^N x_n \ln{y_k} - \left(\sum_{n=1}^N x_n\right) \left( \sum_{k=1}^N \ln{y_k}\right)}{\sum_{k=1}^N \ln^2{y_k}-\left ( \sum_{k=1}^N \ln{y_k}\right)^2} $$

Comment: So putting in the data I gave above, does it solve for the correct C1 & C2? This is exactly what I was looking for, but I was wondering if you could possibly expand on what is going on here, I have to take this and put it in Java. Thank you very much thourgh sir.

Comment: @Braca: see above for explicit results that are program-friendly.  Note that the sums over $k$ may be computed first and then plugged into the above expressions.

Comment: Thank you sir, you been very helpful.

Comment: For a derivation of the least-squares formulation, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_least_squares_(mathematics)#Derivation_directly_in_terms_of_matrices